# how init a val out the object in scala?

Tags: scala

A redis cluster client should should be shared in many place,am I right? with the google, so I use a RedisCli object:

```
 object RedisCli {
   val jedisClusterNodes = new java.util.HashSet[HostAndPort]()
   jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("192.168.1.100", 6379))
   lazy val jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes)
   //...method with jedisCluster 
 }
```

the problem is how can I init the `jedisCluster` out the object--I want init the HostAndPort in the `main` method of other object, get the ip from properties file the file passed by command line. should I just use `class RedisCli` in my circumstance?

I think I am totally lost in class and object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala all members of a singleton objects should be defined. While you are allowed to modify var members from the outside, take a step back and ask yourself what is the point of having a singleton object in your case if each client can modify its members? You will only end up with spaghetti code.

I would highly recommend using a dependency injection framework (Spring for example) where you can create beans in a specific place then inject them where you need them.

In a nutshell [singleton objects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html) should be used when you want to define methods and values (never seen a case where a var is used) that are not specific to each instance of a class (think Java static). In your case, you seem to want different instances (otherwise why should they be set from client code) but want a certain instance to be shared across different clients and this is exactly what dependency injection allows you to do.

If you don't want to use a DI framework and are okay with having clients modify your instances as they please, then simply use a class as opposed to an object. When you use the class keyword, different instances can be instantiated.

```
class RedisCli(val ip: String, val port: Int) {
 val hostAndPort: HostAndPort = new HostAndPort(ip, port)
 etc...
}
```

Hope this helps.